# importing python libraries like keras, numpy etc

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have installed libaries with pip but still get errors while importing them.

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [1], line 2
1 import random
----> 2 import keras
3 import tensorflow as tf
4 import pandas as pd

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'

Comment: If you are new, I highly suggest installs Python using Anaconda (https://www.anaconda.com). It automatically install all the dependencies and update `PATH` , and so on. You should also need to make sure that the environment that you are using are added to the machine `PATH`.

Comment: I have already installed anaconda and used jupyter from there. I used pip installing most of the libraries.
When i use pip it shows that the libraries already installed but when i import it shows error no module named keras or whatever the library is.

Comment: you may have two Pythons installed and `pip` install module for one Python but you run code with other Python. But Pythons don't share modules. If you run code with `python` then use `python -m pip install ...` to install module for this Python. You can also run `print( sys.executable )` to get `/full/path/to/python` and later use `/full/path/to/python -m pip install ...`

Answer (score 1):

Typically this result from multiple python installations on a machine.

When you use the `pip install <package>`a different python on your machine installed the package, than the python which is used if you execute your program.

I would recommend to work with virtual environment to have a "individual" python for every project on your machine.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by the inconsistency between your environment and the pip installation path.

When you use the conda environment, you can use the `conda install keras` command to install.